# nginx not spawning workers when proxying to FastCGI

Tags: windows, nginx, fastcgi, spawn-fcgi

I'm having some trouble with nginx and FastCGI. I'm working on Windows 7 and I have successfully compiled/installed/setup the following items:

- nginx server
- FastCGI library
- spawn-fcgi-win32.exe

I wrote a simple FastCGI application that just sends a message back to the webserver. Here it is a simplified version of the code:

```
while(FCGI_Accept()) {
    hello();
}
```

I spawned a couple of processes by means of `spawn-fcgi-win32.exe` and everything worked OK: accessing to my app from a web browser returned the "hello" message.

However, in order to check concurrency, I changed my application as follows:

```
while(FCGI_Accept()) {
    sleep10(); //sleep 10 seconds
    hello();
}
```

Then, I opened two separate tabs in my browser and accessed to my app. I expected that both tabs returned the "hello" message after 10 seconds but only the first tab returned it after that timeout; the second tab did it after 20 seconds. This is the access log of nginx:

127.0.0.1 - claudi [25/Feb/2015:**17:45:16** +0100] "GET /foo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3664 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"

127.0.0.1 - claudi [25/Feb/2015:**17:45:26** +0100] "GET /foo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3664 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"

Notice that although I sent the requests at roughly the same time, nginx "saw" the second one after 10 seconds. My nginx configuration file sets 4 workers and 1024 connections per worker. Why doesn't nginx spawn two concurrent workers, one per request?

BTW, I've already checked that both FastCGI processes are working by dumping the process id together with the hello message.

Thanks

Comment: _Although several workers can be started, only one of them actually does any work_ http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues

Comment: Use virtual machine with some *nix

Comment: Alexey, thank you for your point! Although I read **THAT** page I missed **THAT** sentence! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper version from here http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/ and use the installer to get php/python/etc.. working.